# ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I get that I should add alias with all the columns and I'm doing so but I'm still getting error.

```
CREATE TABLE MENTIONS AS SELECT
    UM.USER_ID AS U_ID,
    UM.SCREEN_NAME AS USER_SCREEN_NAME,
    UM.MENTION_ID AS M_USER_ID,
    (
        SELECT
            UI.USER_SCREEN_NAME AS MENTIONED_USER
        FROM
            USER_INFO UI
        WHERE
            UI.USER_ID = UM.MENTION_ID
        AND ROWNUM = 1
    )
FROM
    USER_MENTION UM
```

USER_MENTION table

```
 USER_ID       SCREEN_NAME    MENTION_ID
135846337   irisschrijft     774759032636727300
50117969    Chjulian         13769472
14411827    thenriques45     13769472
26681613    ahenotri        252074645
26681613    ahenotri         9796472
158378782   SpringerOpen    9796472
144241914   Kumarappan      252074645
```

User_INFO table:

```
  USER_ID     USER_SCREEN_NAME
 22553325   jasonesummers   
23435691    QRJAM   false   
67421923    inTELEgentMSP   
97393397    knauer0x    
85303739    MarriageTheorem 
3842711     seki    
3036414608  Bayes_Rule  
838677852   BOLIGATOR
```

I'm still getting the above mentioned error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result of your sub-select has no alias.

Comment: Try moving MENTIONED_USER to just outside the end of the sub-query?

Comment: You are creating a table.  The column needs to have a name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lookup the [Oracle Error Message Manual of the current Oracle version](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ERRMG/ORA-00910.htm#ERRMG-GUID-D9EBDFFA-88C6-4185-BD2C-E1B959A97274). Here the error is mentioned but without additional information.

In such a case look up the 
[Oracle Error Message Manual of version 9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903)
For reasons I don't know a lot of error messages have a description in the 9i manual but not in the manuals of higher versions. 9i is a rather old version so the description may be out of date. But it may contain valuable hints.

> **ORA-00998 must name this expression with a column alias**
>   **Cause:** An expression or function was used in a CREATE VIEW statement, but no corresponding column name was specified. When expressions or functions are used in a view, all column names for the view must be explicitly specified in the CREATE VIEW statement.
>   **Action:** Enter a column name for each column in the view in parentheses after the view name.

We don't have a view but a a table that was created by a select. And actually the last expression of the select list is an expression without an alias. So try your statement using an alias for the last expression. So try

```
CREATE TABLE MENTIONS AS SELECT
    UM.USER_ID AS U_ID,
    UM.SCREEN_NAME AS USER_SCREEN_NAME,
    UM.MENTION_ID AS M_USER_ID,
    (
        SELECT
            UI.USER_SCREEN_NAME
        FROM
            USER_INFO UI
        WHERE
            UI.USER_ID = UM.MENTION_ID
        AND ROWNUM = 1
    ) AS MENTIONED_USER
FROM
    USER_MENTION UM
```

The column alias  in the inner select list is useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your query is that each column in the `create table` needs to have a name.  You think you are assigning a name in the sub-select.  However, you are not.

The subquery is just returning a value -- not a value with a name.  So, the `AS MENTIONED_USER` in your version does nothing.  This is a bit tricky, I guess.  One way to think of the scalar subquery is that it is just another expression or function call.  Things that happen inside it don't affect the outer query -- except for the value being returned.

The correct syntax is to put the column alias *outside* the subselect, not *inside* it:

```
CREATE TABLE MENTIONS AS
    SELECT UM.USER_ID AS U_ID, UM.SCREEN_NAME AS USER_SCREEN_NAME, UM.MENTION_ID AS M_USER_ID,
           (SELECT UI.USER_SCREEN_NAME
            FROM USER_INFO UI
            WHERE UI.USER_ID = UM.MENTION_ID AND ROWNUM = 1
           ) AS MENTIONED_USER
    FROM USER_MENTION UM;
```