# error ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to create table from all_tab_columns but it throws me an error.
like error ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias.
i tried to figure it out but not working.

```
Declare

CURSOR c1 IS  

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM (select 'standard_hash(MY_NAME) AS MY_NAME' COLUMN_NAME from DUAL
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE1' AND COLUMN_NAME<>'MY_NAME');

cols  c1%ROWTYPE;
sqlstmt  VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
     LOOP
         FETCH c1 into cols;
         EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
         sqlstmt := sqlstmt ||cols.column_name||',';
      END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   sqlstmt := 'CREATE TABLE TABLE2  AS SELECT '||substr(sqlstmt, 1, length(sqlstmt)-1)||' FROM TABLE1';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlstmt);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstmt;
   EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error '||sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326426/ora-00998-must-name-this-expression-with-a-column-alias)

Comment: @astentx no but its little bit different

Comment: Looks the same to me. In the other question they are trying to create a table with one column as an expression, without giving the expression any name to use for the column. The solution was to name it using `as`.

Comment: A [cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson can you give some example as a answer

Comment: There are many examples in the documentation. Instead of `cursor c1 is select xyz...`, `open c1`, `loop`, `fetch c1 into ...` etc, you just use `for r in (select xyz...) loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be simplified somewhat.

You don't need to declare an explicit cursor and a record type and fetch each row into it, as this is already built into the language as the [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) construction:

```
declare
    sqlStmt long := 'create table table2 as select ';
begin
    for r in (
        select 'standard_hash(my_name) as my_name' column_name
        from   dual
        union
        select column_name
        from   all_tab_columns
        where  table_name = 'TABLE1'
        and    column_name <> 'MY_NAME'
    )
    loop
        sqlStmt := sqlStmt || r.column_name || ', ';
    end loop;

    sqlStmt := sqlStmt || rtrim(sqlStmt,', ') || ' from table1';

    dbms_output.put_line(sqlStmt);
    execute immediate sqlStmt;
end;
/
```

But you can do this without any loop, as the [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) function can already build a comma-separated list for you. It also makes it easier to retain the order of columns in the original table.

```
declare
    selectList  long;
    sqlStmt     long;
begin
    select listagg(
               case column_name
                   when 'MY_NAME' then 'standard_hash(my_name) as my_name'
                   else lower(column_name)
               end, ', '
           ) within group (order by column_id) as select_list
    into   selectList
    from   user_tab_columns c
    where  c.table_name = 'TABLE1';
    
    sqlStmt :=
        'create table table2 pctfree 0 nologging parallel as '||chr(10)||
        'select '||selectList||chr(10)||
        'from table1';

    dbms_output.put_line(sqlStmt||';');
    execute immediate sqlstmt;
end;
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, this is what i looking for, due to column order change , i was planned to get column name form all_tab_columns and may i know some explanation on your create statement

Comment: can i use CLOB, because query length may exceed more than 4000 Characters

Comment: Yes, CLOB will work fine. However, now that you mention it, `listagg` can only return up to 4000 characters, so if your column list + separators exceeds this then you you will need the loop approach.

Comment: but if i use Loop approch then default order of column will be changed, it is possible to tweak loop approach to order by default column ID

Comment: Order by column_id.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give the name to the expression as follows:

```
sqlstmt := 'CREATE TABLE TABLE2  AS SELECT '
           ||substr(sqlstmt, 1, length(sqlstmt)-1)
           ||' as column_name FROM TABLE1'; -- column_name will bre name of the column of new table
```

As it will become the name of the column of newly created table.

Comment: Thanks, so standard_hash(MY_NAME) came as last column, so AS COLUMN_NAME is worked as expected, i have doubt like it will be the same for all table creation that the column selected from dual will be placed at the end of select statement?

Comment: Can you tell me if multiple column SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM (select 'standard_hash(YOUR_NAME)' COLUMN_NAME from DUAL
UNION ELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM (select 'standard_hash(MY_NAME)' COLUMN_NAME from DUAL ... in this scenerio also do we need use as you mentioned?

Comment: There are no multiple columns in the query posted in comment by you. and the query in comment will work as COLUMN_NAME is there as the alias.